# Yocto error: Building libreoffice package fails in do_package task

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, imx6

I would like to integrate **libreoffice** on my [**tx6s-8035 KARO Board**](https://www.karo-electronics.com/856.html?&L=1) using yocto.  I use [**Ka-ro NXP/Freescale Yocto Project Community BSP** recipe layers](https://github.com/karo-electronics/fsl-community-bsp-platform) for yocto distro **krogoth**. I add too the [**meta-office layer**](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-office/) from open-embedded. I have been facing many issues about packages and libraries dependency to build the libreoffice package. The do_compile task work well but the **do_package task fails** with the following error:

```
ERROR: libreoffice-5.0.6.3-r0 do_package: QA Issue: File 
'/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/extensions/mysql-connector- 
ooo/libmysqlclient_r.so' from libreoffice was already stripped, this will 
prevent future debugging! [already-stripped]
WARNING: libreoffice-5.0.6.3-r0 do_package: libreoffice language file 
pattern not found:  /usr/lib/libreoffice/share/template/%{1}
ERROR: libreoffice-5.0.6.3-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing 
task.
ERROR: libreoffice-5.0.6.3-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/sconte/fsl-community- 
bsp/build_8135_cim/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux- 
gnueabi/libreoffice/5.0.6.3-r0/temp/log.do_package.8211
ERROR: Task 11 (/home/sconte/fsl-community-bsp/sources/meta-office/recipes- 
libreoffice/libreoffice/libreoffice.bb, do_package) failed with exit code 
'1'
```

Here is the log.do_package file output: [log.do_package](https://uploadfiles.io/dwulu)

I view in this file that there is **runstrip** function which is executed on the same library it cound not find. What does **runstrip** means? How can i work around this issue?

Comment: (Some hints) Did you check [insane](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-insane) bitbake class? For instance, you can add something like `INSANE_SKIP_${PN}_append = "already-stripped"`

Comment: Thanks Nayfe ! 
Adding `INSANE_SKIP_${PN}_append = "already-stripped"` solve the issue.

Comment: Np, I wasn't sure :) I added an answer just in case

Answer (score 4):

You can add `INSANE_SKIP_${PN}_append = "already-stripped"` to `libreoffice_%.bbappend` recipe to fix this QA error. You can also send a patch upstream by following [README](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/schnitzeltony/meta-office/master/README).

Comment: It's a bit misleading to call this a fix: it's just silencing the error, isn't it?

Comment: @jku it depends if QA error is a false positive or not, and in this case, libmysqlclient_r.so is stripped two times while compiling, so there is no QA problem here for me.

Comment: That's the issue -- binaries shouldn't be stripped automatically unless there's some special reason for it. The skip might be a completely valid way to handle this for the asker, I was just making a comment that it might not be a fix but a workaround.